# Subquery returned more than 1 value. Using merge and tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

Currently I have a big Stored Procedure using a Cursor and inside are two merge statements. Shortly said, I want to populate 2 tables from one big table.

Now, I'm quite new to sql and have read a fair bit to expand my knowledge. During this research I came across many topics where they discussed Cursors and the performance issue they may give.

The current SP (with cursor) works fine, but I'm stuck trying to use my code without the cursor (other POV) and it bugs the hell out of me.

So right now I'm stuck with this little piece of garbage code. I think it's not possible to do it the way I want it but hey I can try right.

Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, ...

Code:

```
MERGE CONTACTS as target
USING STAGING_CONTACTS as source
ON (target.ID = source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        MAIL = (SELECT MAIL FROM STAGING_CONTACTS),
        NAME = (SELECT NAME FROM STAGING_CONTACTS),
        BRAND = (SELECT BRAND FROM STAGING_CONTACTS),
        ID = (SELECT ID FROM STAGING_CONTACTS)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (MAIL, NAME, BRAND, CORESOLEIL_ID)
    VALUES ((SELECT MAIL FROM STAGING_CONTACTS),
        (SELECT NAME FROM STAGING_CONTACTS),
        (SELECT BRAND FROM STAGING_CONTACTS),
        (SELECT ID FROM STAGING_CONTACTS));
```

This is one of the two merge statements I have, this is the smaller one.

Any feedback is welcome!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Merge is a flawed implementation and is very hard to debug later when there are potential data issues. I would NEVER allow anyone to use it in our production databases.  Far better to use an update statement followed by an Insert (Order is important)

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 2):

Remove select statements..Below statement takes care of which table to update using which table..

```
MERGE CONTACTS as target
USING STAGING_CONTACTS as source
```

so your query can be like below

```
  UPDATE SET
        MAIL = MAIL ,
        and so on...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (MAIL, NAME, BRAND, CORESOLEIL_ID)
    VALUES (mail,name,brand,id)
```

you also can aliases like below

```
   MERGE CONTACTS as target
USING STAGING_CONTACTS as source
ON (target.ID = source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
        target.MAIL = source.MAIL,
      and so on..
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (MAIL, NAME, BRAND, CORESOLEIL_ID)
    VALUES (source.all columns....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script..

```
MERGE CONTACTS as target
USING STAGING_CONTACTS as source
ON (target.ID = source.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
       target.MAIL =   source.MAIL ,
        target.NAME =  source.Name,
        target.BRAND = source.BRAND ,
        target.ID =    source.ID 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (MAIL, NAME, BRAND, CORESOLEIL_ID)
    VALUES ( source.MAIL , source.Name, source.BRAND ,source.ID );
```